# "The report definition for report 'Report1' has not been specified"

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc, microsoft-reporting

Copied an existing working report.
Got the error "The report definition for report 'Report1' has not been specified".  Tried some other suggested fixes, but they were not working for me. Finally noticed an associated error of could not find file '\bin\debug\reports\AdminReports\Report1.rdlc'.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
The rdlc file had:
   "Build Action" = "Embedded Resource"; 
   "Copy to Output Directory" = "Do not copy"

FIXED to:
   "Build Action" = "Content"; 
   "Copy to Output Directory" = "Copy if newer"

Reason: Copying files associated with working report and renaming unbeknownst to Visual Studio and doing Add Existing resulted in incorrect default property settings.